# Classpath length when running 32 bit java with ant

Tags: java, maven, ant, jvm, classpath

We work on rewriting the build system for a software company. Their build has lots of generators, that use various 3rd party deps, one of them is whole Weblogic. We have a "depchain" pom, that consists of all weblogic dependencies. When we run some kind of generators with this depchain in classpath, we fail on `CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long` on 32 bit JVM, but everything works well with 64. It's quite obvious, that it fails on the length of the classpath, because every jar in the depchain is the absolute location within .m2 folder (previously they did not have the understanding of binary repository and the classpath was a simple directory). We execute generators with simple antrun plugin executions. Is there a way to make it work on 32bit java, besides trimming the classpath?

---

**UPD** After a day of sweating I finally made it working using @Evgeniy Dorofeev 's idea. I couldn't use mvn plugin because the part of creating the artifact I run in, is executing this generator. So I had to use ant to build a manifest only jar that contains this giant classpath string. The issue that the classpath string used absolute paths, and I had to convert it to relative (MANIFEST.MF format). It was a headache of it's own:

```
        <var name="relative.classpath.property"/>
        <for param="curr.dep" list="${combined_classpath}" delimiter=";">
            <sequential>
                <local name="relative.dep.location"/>
                <property name="relative.dep.location" relative="true" basedir="${project.build.directory}" value="@{curr.dep}"/>

                <local name="classpath.hack.temp"/>
                <propertyregex property="classpath.hack.temp"
                    input="${relative.dep.location}"
                    regexp="\\"
                    replace="\/"
                    default="${relative.dep.location}"
                    global="true"/>


                <var name="relative.classpath.property" value="${relative.classpath.property} ${classpath.hack.temp}"/>
            </sequential>
        </for>
```

And to build a jar with all this stuff later:

```
<jar jarfile="${project.build.directory}/classpath.hack.jar">
  <manifest>
    <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${relative.classpath.property}"/>
  </manifest>
</jar>
```

And then my `<java>` will have only `${project.build.directory}/classpath.hack.jar` in the classpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `Class-Path` attr to your app jar manifest, this is how we do it in Maven

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    ...
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
    ...
  </plugin>
```

this way there's no limit for classpath length

Answer (score 0):

Java's 64-bit `javac` generates the same code as the 32-bit version so you should don't need to use Java 32-bit unless you only have a 32-bit OS.

Java 6 added `directory/*` to include all JARS in a directory and this can shorted a classpath significantly.

The source of your problem is that all 32-bit programs run in the Windows XP/32-bit emulator and has all the same restrictions such as maximum command line length and environment variable length.  Changing/fixing this is something MS themselves didn't try and I suggest you avoid this too.

Comment: Part of the developers simply don't have x64 machines. Sad but true.